# WORKDAY function in excel doesn't accept union of ranges for Holiday parameter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
=WORKDAY(42429, 1, A10:A15+A20:A22)
```

This formula doesn't work in Excel and gives #VALUE error. If I use only one range for Holidays parameter - it works just fine:

```
=WORKDAY(42429, 1, A10:A15)
```

Both ranges contain random dates from March (42429 is last day of February).

How do I make it work with separate ranges so that it would honor both of them and not just one of them?

I tried to create a small VBA script to manually combine ranges and then use result of that combination as Holiday parameter for the WORKDAY function:

```
Function Test1(holidays As Range, timeOffs As Range) As Long()
    Dim r() As Long
    Dim h As Range, t As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    ReDim r(1 To holidays.Cells.Count + timeOffs.Cells.Count)

    For Each h In holidays.Cells
        r(i) = h.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next h

    For Each t In timeOffs.Cells
        r(i) = t.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next t

    Test1 = r

End Function
```

and then

```
=WORKDAY(42429, 1, Test1(A10:A15, A20:A22))
```

However this yields exactly the same result.

I debugged my little script and I can see that returned object is an Array of Long's and it has all the values I want, however Excel for some reason doesn't like this script and its output either and still gives me #VALUE error.

Any hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=WORKDAY(startDate,1,SMALL((Rng1,Rng2,Rng3),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(Rng1,Rng2,Rng3)))))
```

SMALL is able to handle the multiple arguments for the input and gives a single array as the output.

Got this from [here](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/workday-with-non-adjacent-multi-holiday-ranges.4142/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `=Workday.Intl(startDate,endDate,[Weekend],[Holidays])` documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d) or if that isnt there due to older versions `=NETWORKDAYS(startDate,endDate,[Holidays])`documentation [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) you may have to use an array formula confirm with Ctl+Shift+Enter

Comment: that's exactly what I am using. and it doesn't accept merged ranges.